# Real Analysis Beginning Proof...

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Alright, I've been assigned to work through a proof in my RA course and it just has me bogged down at this point.  We're trying to show that If $b^2 > c$ then there exists a positive real number $r$ such that $b-r>c$.  This is an intermediate step in showing that the set $S=\{x|x \in \mathbb{R}, x \geq 0, x^2<c\}$ - essentially that square roots exist.  Thus I can't use anything concerning square roots in my proof.

Obviously I can't choose $r<b-c$ because I can't show that $b-c$ is positive.  I think what I need to choose is some $r$ such that $(b-r)^2 > c$ however I'm just not seeing the how to find this $r$.

Any help on moving forward/direction with this problem is very much appreciated.

Comment: (If you're trying to show that $S$ is bounded above, simply take $x>c$!)

Comment: I guess I'll spell it out specifically: Let $c$ be a positive number. You will prove that there exists a real number whose square is $c$ as follows. Define the set $S$ by $S = \{x \mid x \in \R, x \geq 0, x^2 < c\}$.

Comment: After showing that $S$ is bounded about by $c+1$ we're then asked:   Show that if $b^2>c$, then there exists a positive number $r$ such that $b-r$ is also an upper bound for $S$.

Comment: What does it have to do with the existence of square roots? After showing it is bounded above, you get a supremum  $a$ exists. What you want is to show neither $a^2<c$ nor $a^2>c$ can hold, so $a^2=c$. That is what I am doing in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After showing it is bounded above, you get a supremum, call it $b$, exists. What you want is to show neither $b^2<c$ nor $b^2>c$ can hold, so it must be the case $b^2=c$, that is $\sqrt b=c$. One can always use Archimedianity. The claim is we may take $r=n^{-1}$, $n$ a natural number we'll specify in what follows. 
You want $\left(b-\dfrac 1 n \right)^2>c $. This is $b^2-\dfrac{2b}n+\dfrac 1 {n^2}>c$ or $b^2-c>\dfrac{2b}n-\dfrac 1{n^2}$. Now $b^2-c>0$, so there certainly exists $n$ such that $$n(b^2-c)>2b>2b-\frac 1n$$

Which gives what you want. You can do something completely analogous when assuming $b^2<c$.

Comment: Thank you, - our next step is to do exactly as you've presented.  I didn't consider Archimedes... Still a bit to get my head around but it feels clear.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The claim is false. Take $b=2$ and $c=3.99$. Then, $b^2>c$, but $b<c$ and *a fortiori* $b-r<c$ for any $r>0$.